# C++ boost:asio what happens to server class when session class is deleted

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

This is my first `boost::asio` project and I came up with a code structure that has one server that create several sessions based on connection requests.

The sessions have a timeout mechanism where I control if I´m receiving messages from the clients. If after a period of time no messages are sent from clients, the session deletes itself and the client shall restart the connection to send its data.  - this is the expected behaviour. The clients are small remote units.

This mechanism is working fine, except that I don´t understand what to do after I delete the session on timeout.

Here is the server `StartAccept` and `HandleAccept` functions of the server:

```
void SocketServer::StartAccept()
{
    std::shared_ptr<SocketSession> session = std::make_shared<SocketSession>(ioService);
    acceptor.listen();
    acceptor.async_accept(session->getSessionSocket(), boost::bind(&SocketServer::HandleAccept, this, session, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void SocketServer::HandleAccept(std::shared_ptr<SocketSession> session, const boost::system::error_code& errorCode)
    {
        if (errorCode)
        {
            std::cout << "Error accepting incoming connection: Error: " << boost::system::system_error(errorCode).what();
        }
        else
        {
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket = session->getSessionSocket();
            session->start();
        }

    StartAccept();
}
```

The session itself has the following code:

```
void SocketSession::start()
{
    readTimeout.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
    readTimeout.async_wait(boost::bind(&SocketSession::TimeoutHandler, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    sessionSocket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(readBuffer, MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH), boost::bind(&SocketSession::HandleRead, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void SocketSession::HandleRead(size_t bytesTransferred, const boost::system::error_code& errorCode)
{
    readTimeout.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));

    if (errorCode)
    {
        ss << "Error reading data from session: Error: " << boost::system::system_error(errorCode).what();
        delete this; <<<------- PROBLEM HERE
    }
    else
    {
        std::string data(readBuffer, bytesTransferred);
        std::cout << "Data read:" << data << std::endl;
        start();
    }
}
```

When the timeout is fired and the code reaches `delete this`, the object is destroyed (I´ve logged that in the object destructor) and the whole program goes to
 `double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000000e6d5c0 ***
Aborted (core dumped)` (in my computer) or `*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000020e0140 ***
==` in Coliru.

I´m confused about what´s going on here. I´ve a full running version of the code at [Coliru - link here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/121fb6eba81485d6).

What I expect is to continue running the server waiting for new connections, even if one or more session timeouts.

Help appreciated.

Comment: do not do `delete this;`. just dont.

Comment: Hummm.. Isn´t `HandleRead` going be around inside `boost` forever ?  In some `boost` examples they "suicide" using `delete this`. Remember I´m opening new sessions on every connection request and if this object is not  deleted in some time I´ll have a fair amount of handlers around...

Comment: link to those examples in the comment please.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/server.cpp ie. Never mind, I got the point!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way this works is that your session object is being kept alive by two shared pointers. One in the handler of the timer and one in the handler of the socket.

All you have to do is ensure that the two shared pointers go out of scope.

When your timeout function ends, one shared pointer will go out of scope (if you don't restart the timer) but the one in the socket's read handler will still exist.

So the thing to do is call `cancel()` on your socket. This will cause its handler to fire with the error code containing the code boost::asio::errc::operation_aborted. If you see this error in your read handler, simply exit the function.

The shared pointer will then be dropped because the handler (which holds a copy of it) will be deleted.

Once there are no shared_ptr's keeping you session alive it will be deleted and all resources will be reclaimed.

edit:

also, I noticed you used socket::read_some. This is a common mistake made by asio beginners (myself included!).

Always prefer the free function versions:  `asio::async_read(...)` or `asio::async_read_until(...)`. Then you don't have to take care of short reads.

ASIO is a beautiful library (IMHO) but the documentation assumes that you're an expert!

Comment: So many time spent on something so simple and logical... This is the expected `shared_ptr` behaviour and that´s why I´ve used it!!! Thanks for helping!

Comment: learning ASIO is like learning c++ - it takes ages to learn how to do it well, and once you do it all seems obvious and beautiful. Until then, it's hell.

Comment: I know!! That´s what makes it beautifull... Hopefully we have SO friends to help...